# How to align text boxes in a vertical manner

Tags: jquery

I have two text boxes which are created dynamically .How to make them align correct position.
I mean i have

```
PhoneNo:123646
1234455
Now i have to get a output as 
PhoneNo:123646 
        1234455
```

Is it possible to do like that.Those Phone numbers in textboxes are dynamically created at the output.

Comment: can you please add the html which is generated?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/4nLge5se/2/

Comment: Please try my answer. If its notwoking add a comment below my answer

Answer (score 0):

A combination of this html:

```
<div>
    <div class="container label">PhoneNumbers:</div>
    <div id="numberToAdd" class="container"></div>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
.container
{
    display: inline-block
}

.label
{
    vertical-align: top
}

.phoneNumbers
{
    display: block
}
```

And then add the phoneNumbers class to your text boxes will do the trick for you. Here is a fiddle of it in action

http://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/6kL61kw1/

If that is not it then you'll need to add more detail to your question for me to be more helpful.

Comment: Its dynamically created. You cannot write this HTML.

Comment: @RinoRaj If you look at the fiddle I included you'll notice that the input textbox DOM elements _are_ being created using jquery as per the problem outlined. The above is just the framework you would need to insert the text boxes into to make it work. Although provided the code you generated used similar divs and css this solution is still correct. More than anything this can be taken as an example of how to solve the extrememly loosely defined problem in the question. Either way this still does solve the problem as presented.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nagabhavani/4nLge5se/2/ this is the HTML provided.. Please see the HTML

Comment: Yes, I saw that and my solution still holds true even given that fiddle. Although, I was hoping not to have to do Naga's job for her. My post was merely an example. Never the less, here is a forked fiddle which has Naga's fiddle with my solution built into it.

Of course this makes the Phone Numbers section look a little weird in the context of the rest of the form but this can be fixed using the same sort of principals, I won't be doing that work as I think this fiddle sufficiently proves that my solution works.

https://jsfiddle.net/ozrevulsion/jxnukzmn/

Answer (score 0):

Generate it in tabular format

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Phone No 1:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="phoneno1"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label>Phone No 2:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="phoneno2"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Its dynamically created. You cannot write this HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offSetValue = $('.append').offset().left - 8;
    $(".append:gt(0)").css('margin-left',offSetValue+'px');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/yar83oog/1/)

But the above example won't work for dynamically crated elements. Only for showing a demo I wrote that. To make it wok write the function below.

```
function checkDOMChange()
{
    // check for any new element being inserted here,
    // or a particular node being modified
    // call the function again after 100 milliseconds

    addStyle();

    setTimeout( checkDOMChange, 100 );
}

function addStyle(){
    var offSetValue = $('.append').offset().left - 8;
    $(".append:gt(0)").css('margin-left',offSetValue+'px');
}
```